# How to make a model changes visible on a JDatePicker?

Tags: java

After doing

```
Date date = new Date();
jDatePicker.getModel().setValue(date);
```

I'd like my `JDatePicker` to display the new value in the UI. I tried

```
jDatePicker.repaint();
```

which doesn't have any effect.

I'm using `JDatePicker` 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.

Answer (score 0):

`JDatePicker.getModel().setValue(Date)` works fine and correctly updates the GUI (I was looking on the wrong component). `JDatePicker.repaint()` isn't necessary.